# GPUImage GPUImageFalseColorFilter giving wrong color and coloring transparent areas

Tags: ios, uiimage, gpuimage

I have a green button with a white icon and title. I am trying to use the GPUImage library that I just learned about to change the green to blue, but keep the white as white. Here is my code:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pause-button"];
GPUImageFalseColorFilter *colorSwapFilter = [[GPUImageFalseColorFilter alloc] init];
colorSwapFilter.firstColor = (GPUVector4){0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
colorSwapFilter.secondColor = (GPUVector4){1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
UIImage *filteredImage = [colorSwapFilter imageByFilteringImage:inputImage];
```

There are 2 problems:

1. The resulting image is a pale purple instead of blue. Almost as though the blue is being overlaid with a 50% opacity or something and the original green was set to white.
2. The button isn't a rectangle (more of an oval), and the transparent areas of the PNG (the corners) are now filled in with a semi-transparent blue (well, pale purple actually). Basically the button is now a rectangle with a darker oval in the middle.

Am I using this filter incorrectly? Do I have to do some pre-processing before using this filter?

Answer (score 1):

The GPUImageFalseColorFilter is probably not what you want to use to alter the hue of something. It's a reimplementation of the filter by the same name in Core Image, which first converts an image to its luminance and then replaces white with one color and black with another. Instead of a grayscale, you get a variable mix between these colors. I also don't think it respects alpha channels at present.

You might want something more like a GPUImageHueFilter (again, not sure if it respects alpha) or a GPUImageLookupFilter. You might need to build a custom filter to locate a color within a certain threshold (look at the chroma keying ones for that) and to replace that with your given color. Hue changes might do the job, though.